# At the end of "Kamisama no Iutoori 2", does Ushimitsu has to imagine every person to fulfill his desire?

Tags: kamisama-no-iutoori

In the last 5 chapters and final game of *Kamisama no Iutoori 2* manga:

> Acid Mana explained that we can only bring the image we have of the person, and not an actual person with its real personality.

But in the last chapter:

> After Ushimitsu remained as the only god, he decided to reset the world or as he said "go back in time" and meet Akashi again not as a participant but as the game master.

So here is my question:

> Does that mean Ushimitsu has to imagine every person who has died and bring them back again?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. We prefer title that gives context than a vague title. I decided to retitled it based on my understanding of the question (I don't follow the series though). If the meaning is incorrect, feel free to [edit] and improve the title.

Comment: The thing is in this manga, almost any character can die even the main cast, and the title spoils the fate of this character.
Also thanks for adding the tag!